# Return all values if where clause doesn't return any records

Tags: sql-server

I have the following query

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE ID = @ID
```

I want to return all records in the table if the `where` clause does not return any records. Any suggestions?

Comment: What about `Select * From table1 Where ID = @ID`? There is no `ALL` keyword, I think...

Comment: @deHaar Already edited that brother

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `NOT EXISTS()`

```
Select * From table1 Where ID = @ID 
OR NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM table1 where ID = @ID)
```

Comment: How would this be used if there where multiple conditions in the where clause? And if any one of them didn't return any rows, then select all rows? Thanks

Comment: If performance is not an issue, just use multiple `OR NOT EXISTS` same as used here.

Comment: What if performance was an issue? Can you please direct on the right direction, you don't have to give me an answer since you provided the answer to the original question. Thanks

Comment: I would suggest trying it and see if it is an issue or not.. I'm not sure how would you do it differently.. sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify what you want to see if `@ID` *is* found in the table.  What should happen then?

1. Return that one row => use @sagi's answer
2. Return an empty rowset => modify @sagi's answer to remove the `ID = @ID` predicate from the where clause, leaving just the `not exists` predicate.
3. Return nothing at all =>

```sql
if not exists (select 1 from table1 where ID = @ID)
    select * from table1;
```